# influence of neucleophiles in substituition reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

in the image the substitution  reaction of 1-bromobutane and 2-bromobutane is shown. In presence of NaCN 1-bromobutane reacts fast and with the other it becomes slow, which is understandable since CN-  is a poor leaving group compared to Br-.

But OH- is a poorer leaving group compared to CN-(pKa of HCN and water is 9.1 and 16 respectively) , so shouldn't the substitution reaction of 1-bromobutane with water be even faster than it's reaction with NaCN instead of slowing down?

the image was taken from: http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/06/27/two-types-of-substitution-reactions/ and a detailed discussion is given here